# Isn't truly asynchronous, non-blocking javascript impossible?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, nonblocking

So, am I missing something here?

**All** javascript engines in popular modern browsers (as of 2011) are ***single-threaded***.

This means while EVENTS can occur asynchronously, they are still queued (in "single-file") to be executed.

This means that all these techniques to load external javascript into an HTML page, they are really only to allow the **download** to happen asynchronously, the execution of the downloaded code however, always happens one (function) at a time, one file at a time.

So other "tips" I've seen on the web to breakup and execute initializing code blocks using setTimeout, that would be bogus, incorrect advice - the timer is also a single-file queue and executes only in order. With setTimeout you are just causing an out-of-order execution via the timer and allowing other events in the browser (ie. mouse clicks or keypress, etc.) to jump in the queue - that in itself might be good to have, but it's certainly not asynchronous code execution.

If I'm right, there's a bunch of bad, misunderstood advice out there that's too often repeated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aren't you confusing asynchronicity with concurrency? It's true there isn't any *concurrency* in the browser JS environment (aside from web workers, and anything the browser does internally, like I/O and rendering), but *asynchronicity* just means that all calls are non-blocking, and control flow always returns immediately.

Your definitions of 'blocking'/'non-blocking' aren't clear either. The wide-spread meaning of a blocking function call is that it doesn't return control to the caller until all computation, I/O, etc. has completed. This says nothing about concurrency.

Comment: Maybe there's a more specific definition but I understood "asynchronous" to be *processes that happen independently of each other* (ie. without being in "lockstep"). To me, that implies multi-threading. Returning control back immediately is "non-blocking" so I agree with that definition.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't call the SO tag wiki an authoritative source.  Wikipedia has somewhat higher standards of accuracy, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous says "In programming, asynchronous events are those occurring independently of the main program flow. Asynchronous actions are actions executed in a non-blocking scheme, allowing the main program flow to continue processing." It then goes into detail and links to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O which is pretty thorough. Nowhere does it even imply concurrent user code execution.

Comment: Maybe this is what you mean: one way of implementing an asynchronous interface is to wrap synchronous calls in worker threads, which then trigger an event in the main thread. The API's user never actually has to deal with any concurrency issues directly.

Comment: On the other hand, you do not need to use an asynchronous model to implement concurrency. Many Java-based servers use a threaded, synchronous execution model; servlets are by default completely synchronous, for example. The Unix fork-on-accept server model is the same: one process per connection (hence concurrency), but the calls are synchronous. Hence, asynchronicity and concurrency are entirely orthogonal.

Comment: FWIW, I realise this is kind of a semantic issue, but your question is pretty semantic in nature. For practical purposes, the setTimeout() tricks aren't wrong - basically, the idea is to let control flow back to the browser's main event handler so your code can respond to user input. This is one of the drawbacks of the asynchronous model: you can't explicitly invoke the event handler other than by returning flow control to it. Conversely, in a synchronous model with Green threads, you can implement a magic "handle events" function which blocks until other events are done.

Comment: Ah good point (about the setTimeout purpose). Here's another question regarding this concept - how about frames/iframes? Does a single javascript thread execute between all frames? Or can a browser establish a new thread for frames? How about external windows started by a parent document, they can communicate and change variables if opened from the same scope - is this a loophole for javascript threading? I know Chrome keeps isolated threads for tabs, but tabs in the same scope (same domain) can communicate, how does the threading handle that? Or do they use the same thread for those cases?

Comment: Good question, this actually goes beyond my knowledge, sorry. You may have more success asking that as a new question or maybe finding out from browser makers directly.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Javascript is asynchronous in the sense that, although it runs on one thread, said thread is running concurrently to other threads executing other actions (page rendering, for instance) independently of the Javascript engine.

The definition, I think, does not mean to state that the Javacsript itself can be executed in any order - that's linear and in accordance with scope.

Comment: Ah good point that even though javascript itself is single-threaded, it still runs in parallel to rendering requests. But that still means javascript itself can only make one rendering request at a time anyway (ie. resize div to the full screen, and insert text, can only happen one after another)

Answer (score 1):

You're right about how JavaScript engines work in single pages, w/r/t `setTimeout` and such. (Generally speaking, this is a good thing because it makes writing JavaScript and reasoning about the code much easier.) In case you haven't read it, jQuery's Jon Resig wrote a [solid explanation of JavaScript's timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Truly asynchronous JavaScript **in the browser** is defined by the Web Workers API.

- [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers) (Wikipedia)
- [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers) (MDC)
- [John Resig on Web Workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)

Comment: Great links, thanks. But since it's not even in IE9, Microsoft is again holding us back?

Comment: Only if you're forced to support IE. Alternately, you _could_ write separate code for browsers that do and don't support web workers. It wouldn't be fun, but it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the new HTML5 "web worker" facility, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

[Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers) are just for that. Although due to poor browser availability they might not be the solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript guru, so this is just my musing, but it would appear to me that you might be partially right.

However, if you think of the Javascript thread as "time" and allow other functions to jump in the flow of time wherever you need them, then it makes javascript essentially act like a non-blocking process.

On the other hand, HTML 5 defines web workers, which (if I'm understanding it correctly), IS "multi-threaded," in the sense that many can be processing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Single thread yes, but that does not exclude async.  Async processing and threaded processing are totally different.  In fact, mouse clicks and key presses are usually the only thing ppl are tying to accomplish with setTimeout. Let the Gui have time to interact during number crunching.