# Does Node.js really do the background I/O tasks asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, asynchronous

Edit: We can close. [Isn't truly asynchronous, non-blocking javascript impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434270/isnt-truly-asynchronous-non-blocking-javascript-impossible)

---

```
var PATH = require ("path");
var URL = require ("url");

var sleep = function (ms){
    var start = new Date ().getTime ();
    while ((new Date ().getTime () - start) < ms);
}

require ("http").createServer (function (req, res){
    if (URL.parse (req.url).pathname === "/1"){
        console.log ("tab 1: I'm in");
        PATH.exists ("test", function (exists){

            sleep (5000);

            res.writeHead (200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.end ("1");
            console.log ("tab 1: I'm done");
        });
    }else{
        console.log ("tab 2: I'm in");
        res.writeHead (200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end ("2");
        console.log ("tab 2: I'm done");
    }
}).listen (80);
```

1. Copy the content into a file.
2. Execute the file.
3. Open a new tab in browser. Set the url to `localhost/1`. Don't go yet.
4. Open a new tab in browser. Set the url to `localhost/2`. Don't go yet.
5. Go back to the first tab. Press enter and immediately after change to the second tab and press enter.

Result:

- console log:

  tab 1: I'm in
  tab 1: I'm done
  tab 2: I'm in
  tab 2: I'm done
- Tab 1 waits 5 seconds to receive the result "1".
- Tab 2 also has to wait 5 seconds because tab 1 is sleeping for 5 seconds.

The docs says that all is asynchronous except the code. Only one thread. Only one request at a time. Requests are enqueued.

I/O calls are supposed to be asynchronous, right? Then why tab 2 has to wait to tab 1 if the callback comes from an asynchronous I/O process?

Thanks.

Comment: having a fake `sleep` method in node is *ragequit*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `sleep` is blocking the event loop.

Replace it with `setTimemout(function() { /* Code to run */ }, 5000);` and watch `/2` respond immediately.

The actual I/O is asynchronous, but all actions you're performing on the I/O happen in the event loop. If something is blocking the event loop, everything else has to wait, just like you said.

EDIT. For more clarity, look at the following ASCII graphic:

```
Event Loop Thread: ------+req1HandlerExistsCall+-------+req1Wait5Sec++++++++++++++++++++++++++req2ExistsCall+-------+req2Immediate+-------------
         HTTP I/O: -+req1+--------------------------------------+req2+--------------------------------------+req1Response+--------+req2Response+
         File I/O: ----------------------------+exists1+----------------------------------------------------+exists2+---------------------------
```

Basically, only one at a time for each thread. Because the first request handler blocks for 5 seconds (and it's essentially impossible to beat your filesystem with your fingers in a speed test), the second response doesn't even start to be handled until the first request is almost done.

Comment: Then, is the exists() function synhronous? Then why there are 2 functions to test if a file exists? (exists() and existsSync()). Thanks

Comment: No, ``exists`` is asynchronous, but each event is executed linearly on a single thread, so your ``sleep`` command blocks all action for 5 seconds. Let me edit my post with an ASCII graphic to better explain.

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused with asynchrony and concurrency. Now I see that node.js works the same way as the traditional browser event-loop (timeouts, ajax, etc).

Comment: Well, with the caveat that you can spawn ``child_process``es in Node.js and have actual parallelism (but no memory sharing, only message passing, to avoid the whole locking/mutex complexity).

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have any I/O calls in your code
2. You are calling a busy sleep method in your code ie your code is taking 5 seconds to process. And while it is processing nothing else can run on that instance

Honestly, is this a real question or are you just trying to bash node?

Comment: The question is so real as most other questions here.

Comment: You must be ultra clever. Remove the downvote please. It's a REAL question.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep is implemented in blocking manner and runs on the very engine that is being single threaded.

`SetTimeout` method is the equivalent version of waiting some time in JavaScript.

Also consider, that in JavaScript most thing should involve a resultHandler as continuation is handled with function typed parameters to other functions to be invoked when the job is done.